# Implementing Unit Of Work using GenericRepository with MVC 5 /EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

**UPDATE 3:**

I see this video and how the author emphasize to use Repository/UOW...as oppose to what i discouraging.
btw author is using ORM(EF)

```
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As I was playing with the Repository and I have this scanrio to tackle and I'm not sure if I'm following the right direction...
So in my controller:

```
public class PersonsController : Controller
{
    GenericRepository<Person> _genericRepository = new GenericRepository<Person>(new PersonsContext()); 

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GenericRepository<Actors> _genericActorRepository = new GenericRepository<Actors>(new PersonsContext());
        IEnumerable<Actors> _actorList = _genericActorRepository.GetAll();
        //IList<Actors> _actorList1 = _genericActorRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        ViewBag.ActorList = new SelectList(_actorList);
        return View(_genericRepository.GetAll());
    }
```

}

UPDATE:

Here is the [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Repository-Pattern-in-MVC5-0bf41cd0) of Microsoft Developer Network talks about GenericRepository!

I am trying to implement best practices during the design phase of a system. I am going to be using Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC 5 C#, and the generic repository/unit of work pattern (hopefully).

My question: how do I introduce Unit Of Work in my GenericRepository?

Here is my GenericRepository class:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable
{
    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id);        
    IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    Task EditAsync(TEntity entity);
    Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity);
    Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity);
}  

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public GenericRepository() {}

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public async Task EditAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
    {

        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        //if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        //{
        //    dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        //}
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
        {
            _dbContext.Dispose();
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Model class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Fullname { get; set; }
    public String Profession { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Context:**

```
public class PersonsContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonsContext() : base("name=PersonsContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class PersonsController : Controller
{
    GenericRepository<Person> _genericRepository = new GenericRepository<Person>(new PersonsContext()); 
    //
    // GET: /Persons/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_genericRepository.GetAll());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Persons/Details/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Int32 id)
    {
        Person person = await _genericRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Persons/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Persons/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _genericRepository.InsertAsync(person);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Persons/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Int32 id)
    {
        Person person = await _genericRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Persons/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _genericRepository.EditAsync(person);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: All are great answers and I'm learning something new as oppose to what I have been reading on Microsoft Developer Network, I'm not sure why the authors (blogs/site...) raised up the awareness as when and why you should think of implementing Repository/UOF or Service Layer...uff

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that most of the Microsoft people that publish samples aren't in the business of writing real world code most of the time.  They're usually support and/or evangelist type people.  It's their job to "show off" the tools and what they can do, not necessarily to tell you exactly how to write large maintainable projects.  This is one of the cases where the Microsoft demo machine latched onto something (uow/gr) and they keep publishing new articles about it.  Both uof and gr are both good patterns, which is why EF implements them.  But no reason to do it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

This has largely become an anti-pattern in my opinion.  Using a Unit of Work and Repository is important and good design, *BUT* most people overlook the fact that Entity Framework is already an implementation of Unit of Work and Generic Repository.

Only implement your own UoW and Generic Repository on top of EF if you truly feel it's necessary (say, you intend to support different kinds of data access) or you believe your application will be exceptionally long lived and require a lot of ongoing maintenance.  If your app is relatively simple, and/or is unlikely to change a lot, then there is no reason to implement additional abstractions.

I don't suggest directly using EF code in your controller, so you should use some kind of data abstraction, such as a service layer or concrete repository (as opposed to generic, a concrete repository has methods like `GetCustomers()` that abstracts the business logic into a method).

Another reason to implement your own UoW or Generic Repository is if you're not going to use an ORM that supports UoW, in that case you would need your own implementation.

Comment: I'm learning something new as oppose to what I have been reading on Microsoft Developer Network, I'm not sure why the authors (blogs/site...) raised up the awareness as when and why you should think of implementing Repository/UOF or Service Layer...uff –

Comment: I have updated my question and I'm confused now if what I'm doing is the right way of doing so I have GenericRepository and also I have created GenericActorRepository to get me the data for Actor entity. please have a look.

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Microsoft has recently changed their guidance on this, see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application#repo

Comment: @Erik Sure, EF makes you data model independent, but what allows you to be EF independent when you need to move to a faster or lighter weight ORM?

Comment: @DaveMorganTexas - replacing your data layer is not a good enough reason to implement another heavy abstraction layer like UoW on top of an existing UoW.  On top of that, almost everyone that implements such an abstraction does so in such a way that makes it highly specific to EF anyways (for instance, passing an IQueryable back to your other layers) which means you often have EF specific Linq queries in your business layers.  Swapping out your data layer is seldom that simple with a leaky abstraction such as this.

Comment: That's full of assumptions.  UoW facade to DbContext doesn't have to be "heavy".  Not everyone passes up IQueryable above the domain layer.  "You're probably glued to EF anyway." is a pretty poor argument to permanently cement yourself to it.

Comment: @DaveMorganTexas - I didn't say you should permanently cement yourself  to it.  I said, that implementing another UoW is not the right way to do it.  If replacability is your goal, then UoW is not your solution.  For example, UoW and GR doesn't provide an easy way to create complex queries, with Includes, which means you are now stuck using lazy loading, which means you are now dependent upon an abstraction that requires lazy loading to work, which now means you have to deal with N+1 problems.  You simply cannot create a non-leaky Generic  UoW/Generic Repository in any non-trivial application

Comment: @DaveMorganTexas - Putting another UoW on top of a UoW is like putting a second firewall in front of another firewall and thinking you get twice the security.  You don't, you just get more complexity and twice the problems.  UoW solves specific problems.  Putting a second UoW in place doesn't solve them twice as well.  You're trying to solve a different problem (data agnosticicism) with the wrong tool.

Comment: @Erik not true.  It is only one level of indirection that isolates dependencies upon EF.  EF can be too heavy for certain high-performance websites.  I am all for waiting until it is needed, but when it is, it is nice to be able to make the change.  I will post the UoW I recommend.

Comment: @DaveMorganTexas - Please explain how you manage to do things like complex queries, .Includes(), Paging, Sorting, Filtering, all without exposing your IQueryable outside of your UoW/GR?  If you're doing those things inside your repository, then it's no longer a generic repository by definition, it becomes a concrete repository.  This is the problem... either you have to expose leaky abstractions to give control to the upper layers, or your are no longer making them generic..

Answer (score 2):

Generally, avoid including unnecessary abstractions to your code just because you read somewhere it's *best practice*. 
If you are not able to justify abstractions, you are better avoiding them. You can easily refactor your code later and add as many layers as required.
It's a bad idea to over complicate your implementation if your answer is *maybe I will need that in future*.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's typically an anti-pattern to layer a generic repository over Entity Framework. The Entity Framework *is* your generic repository, and it already implements the Unit-of-Work pattern. In my own code, I skip the "repository" layer (since I'm using EF), and instead either call directly into the EF code from my controllers, or if the logic is complex or needs to be used in multiple places, I'll add in a Services layer over the top of EF which has actual business logic (i.e., if you add 'x', you always need a 'y' to go along with it, that sort of thing). The MVC code - and code from other places too - will then call into the Services layer, but the Services layer is not and can't be generic.

The reason why you sometimes *used* to implement a generic repository over EF was for testability - it was a lot easier to mock out your own generic repository than to mock out EF. But these days, EF is reasonably mockable - no sniggers please - so long as you're careful about your Include() statements and a few other gotchas along the way.

Comment: I believe that it IS reasonable to implement a generic repository over EF. This makes moving to another RDBMS much easier. Sure, this is not likely to happen too often, but it does happens. Imagine that the other RDBMS does not support working with EF? You'd be happy to have that additional layer then.

Comment: @JensH - You would probably be wrong.  A generic repository is typically extremely tightly coupled to EF, because you are almost certainly passing direct linq expressions.  This often is often very EF specific and would require rewriting your queries to be generic rather than EF specific anyways.  A concrete repository is a better choice than a generic one.  A service layer would be even better.  Don't add unnecessary abstractions simply on the off chance you might do something in the future.

Comment: @JensH - If you think it's likely (not just possible) that you'll end up swapping out EF for something else (e.g., NHibernate), then, yeah, it might make sense to add this extra level. But for 99% of the folks out there, I think it falls into the category of YAGNI: it's extra trouble that would be of marginal value even if you actually did need it, and in all probability, you won't need it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _dbContext = new MyNameSpace.MyDbContext();
    private readonly bool _readOnly;

    public UnitOfWork(bool readOnly = false)
    {
        _readOnly = readOnly;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    internal DbContext GetDbContext()
    {
        return _dbContext;
    }

    internal bool ReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return _readOnly;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, a generic repository like:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    private DbQuery<TEntity> _dbQuery;
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _dbContext = unitOfWork.GetDbContext();
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        if (unitOfWork.ReadOnly)
        {
            _dbQuery = _dbSet.AsNoTracking();
        }
        else
        {
            _dbQuery = _dbSet;
        }
    }

    public GenericRepository()
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbQuery;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbQuery.Where(predicate);
    }

    public async Task EditAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

If you decide later that you want a lightweight ORM, you are not glued to it.

You can migrate your IQueryable references to specific methods on your repository that do not couple as tightly, and port the EF generated SQL to the lightweight ORM, or direct ADO.Net that you prefer.

Comment: Repository layer consumes only the Entities layer.  Service/Domain layer exposes only domain models, while consuming only the entities and repository.  This can be refactored into direct sql to domain models by analyzing the generated sql if the performance is needed.

Comment: You swore up and down above that you did not expose IQueryable from your data layer in your Generic Repository, and you claimed I was making "assumptions" for suggesting you did.  Well, looks like you are.  As soon as you explose IQueryable, you have now tied your upper layers to EF because IQueryable has very specific ties to EF's SQL translation that is not portable from one data layer to another.  This is why it's a leaky abstraction.  Read http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Comment: Here's another one, although he argues for exposing IQueryable, his argument is that the benefits of the leaky abstraction outweight the loss of replacability.  http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/should-my-repository-expose-iqueryable.html

Comment: The point here is, by exposing IQueryable from your Generic Repository, you are tightly coupling anything that consumes it to Entity Framework, essentially nullifying your extra abstraction layer.  If you replace EF with, say, Dapper or nHibernate, you will have to go through and rewrite many of your calls to your Generic Repository because they will no longer work, again due to the fact that IQueryable is tightly coupled to the underlying SQL translation, as well as additional "features" like includes and behavior like lazy loading which may or may not be present in your new layer.

Comment: I have actually been through this conversion of data technologies when using a UoW and GR, I know first hand the problems that exist.  I assume you have not since you would also know these problems if you had (either that or your application was too trivial to run into them).  I assure you, IQueryable is not database technology agnostic.

Comment: @Erik  I have read that, it is really rude of you to assume I didn't.  A generic repository is not the end.  I spoke of migrating IQueryable reference specific methods.  Why do you assume so many strawmen just for the sake of "winning an argument".  If you keep all of your references to IQueryable and to the entities in the domain layer and you expose only view models/service models/DTOs, then you not only prevent any of your business logic leaking into your controllers, but your controllers become trivial and api controllers even moreso.

Comment: Conversion is also trivial.  One linq query becomes one specific method on your repository implementation.  Again, I said: "You can migrate your IQueryable references to specific methods on your repository that do not couple as tightly."  Then you threw the Seeman article in my face when you were the one originally saying: "The situation is just too bad to ever be helped."  So please, no rage posting.